# How to handle the exceptions thrown by CompletableFuture.supplyAsync

Tags: java-8

I have the following block of code. I am getting `org.springframework.web.context.request.async.AsyncRequestTimeoutException` the catch block is not handling that. Can anyone tell me how to handle the exception thrown by the below `supplyAsync` block?

```
 @org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Async
    public CompletableFuture<ResponseEntity<?>> getTeam(String teamCode) {
        CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            CricketTeam team;
            try {
                team = service.getTeamInfo(teamCode);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Error error = new Error(500, ex.getMessage());
                return new ResponseEntity<>(error, HttpStatus.OK);
            }
            return new ResponseEntity<>(team, HttpStatus.OK);
        });

}
```

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the whole thing with a try/catch statement?

Comment: you mean the whole supplyAsync block?

Comment: What is `error`? Besides, you can only catch exception thrown within the `try` body. You didn’t make clear, where the `AsyncRequestTimeoutException` is thrown.

Comment: it is throwing from the service method. but the catch is not handling that.. I have updated the code [added the @Async]

Comment: it is a user defined type with error code and error message..

Comment: Just a hint: if you don’t know what causes the error, you should not generously remove things from the code, ending up with something impossible to break. Try to post code, capable of reproducing the problem, instead of some fragments, not even compilable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe something like this (you'll have to adjust the types):

```
    CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> possiblyFailingMethod())
            .exceptionally((e) ->
                    {
                        log.error("Something went wrong", e);
                        return "KO";
            });
```